# Using CSOM in C# to Dynamically Load Project Server Columns From Selected Rows

Tags: sharepoint, csom, ms-project-server-2010, ms-project-server-2013

I use CSOM .NET to load task objects from Project Server 2013, and I need to

- filter tasks so that only a subset of them is returned, and
- load only a subset of task columns, specified at runtime by the user.

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291022/dynamically-loading-project-online-properties-via-csom) that shows how to load a dynamic set of columns, and it works nicely for my second requirement.  However, I cannot figure out a workable LINQ syntax to combine **both** column selection and row filtering.

In the example below, I need to load only those "rows" for summary tasks (where *t.IsSummary* is *true*), and I want to load only the *Name*, *Start*, and *Finish* columns.

The following code from the referenced post loads just the three columns that I need:

```
foreach (string fieldName in new List<string>(){"Name","Start","Finish"});
{
  ctx.Load(ctx.Tasks,c => c.Include(t => t[fieldName]));
}
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

But when I try to combine *where()* and *include()* in the only syntax that makes sense to me, I get *InvalidQueryExpressionException* on second iteration through the foreach loop: "The query expression is not supported."

```
foreach (string fieldName in new List<string>(){"Name","Start","Finish"});
{
    ctx.Load(ctx.Tasks,
    c => c.Where(t => t.IsSummary),
    c => c.Include(t => t[fieldName])
    );
}

ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

I get the same error if I reverse the order of *where* and *include* clauses. If I pull the *where* clause outside of the loop over field names and make it a separate *Load* call, the summary-task row filtering works, but I lose the dynamic selection of tasks fields.  There must be a syntax in LINQ for CSOM that meets both requirements.  What is the correct syntax to do this type of query?

Answer (score 0):

The following example demonstrates how to apply select and filter operators  in SharePoint CSOM API:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());

var result = ctx.LoadQuery(items.Where(i => (bool)i["IsSummary"]).Include(i => i["Name"], i => i["Start"], i => i["Finish"]));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["Name"]);    
}
```

So, i believe the following expression is supported in Project Server CSOM API:

```
var result = ctx.LoadQuery(ctx.Tasks.Where(t => (bool)t["IsSummary"]).Include(t => i["Name"], t => t["Start"], t => t["Finish"]));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.   Yes, CAML would solve my problem, but there is no way to invoke CAML with Project Server CSOM.  It works for  SharePoint lists but not for Project Server objects such as projects and tasks.     Your second idea will work, but it is not dynamic.  Rather it is hard-coded for the three fields "Name", "Start", and "FInish".   What I need is a method that will include an arbitrary list of fields; there may be 3 fields or there may be 10 fields.

Comment: A simpler explanation of what I need:  I need a way to specify the included fields at runtime rather than at compile time.   So I cannot write code that specifically includes just the three fields of "Name", "Start", and "Finish".  Instead I need code that can include an arbitrary list of N fields at runtime.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I answered this myself by using expression trees, which let you filter a set of rows and select a set of columns based on parameters that are only known at runtime.  In the example below, I simulate finding out at runtime that I need to filter the tasks on the *IsSummary* column and that I should retrieve only the five columns *Id*, *Name*, *Start*, *IsSubProject*, and *Finish*.   Here's the code:

```
        using System.Linq.Expressions;

        // Input parms discovered at runtime
        string filterColumnName = "IsSummary";
        List<string> columnNames = new List<string>(
          new[] { "Id", "Name", "Start", "IsSubProject", "Finish" });

        //  Get the client object for the Published Project matching projGuid
        ctx.Load(ctx.Projects, c => c.Where(p => p.Id == projGuid));
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        PublishedProject proj = ctx.Projects.Single();

        // Compute the expression tree for filtering the task rows
        var taskParm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(PublishedTask), "t");
        var predicate = Expression.PropertyOrField(taskParm, filterColumnName);
        var filterExpression = Expression.Lambda<
                Func<PublishedTask, bool>>(predicate, taskParm);

        //  Dynamically generate expression tree for each column to be included
        var colSelectionList = new List<Expression<
                Func<PublishedTask, object>>>();

        foreach (var colName in columnNames)
        {
            var fldExpr = Expression.PropertyOrField(taskParm, colName);
            var fldAsObjExpr = Expression.Convert(fldExpr, typeof(object));
            var colSelectorExpr = Expression.Lambda<
                 Func<PublishedTask, object>>(fldAsObjExpr, taskParm);
            colSelectionList.Add(colSelectorExpr);
        }

        //  Create query using LoadQuery (Load does not work here)                  
        var taskList = ctx.LoadQuery(proj.Tasks
                        .Where(filterExpression)
                        .Include(colSelectionList.ToArray())
                        );

        //  Execute the query
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        // taskList now contains just the filtered rows and selected columns
```

I hope this helps someone else who is stuck on using CSOM to do this for Project Server.  I found these two references helpful:
[At MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654267.aspx)
and [at Second Life of a Hungarian SharePoint Geek](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2014/06/15/how-to-filter-the-results-of-client-object-model-requests-sent-from-powershell-on-the-server-side-implementing-the-where-method/)

..Jim